# "reported no ..." vs. "did not report ..."

Tags: differences

Is there a difference in meaning between "John reported no symptoms" and "John did not report any symptoms"?

I always felt that there is a subtle difference between the two, former implying that John **was asked** whether he had any symptoms and he explicit said no, but latter implying that John **was not asked** about his symptoms and he did not spontaneously report any symptoms.

Am I completely off the track here?

Comment: The two can be synonymous, or there can be a shade of difference. If I report "no symptoms" it is an active statement confirming a positive finding. If I do not report symptoms, I may have omitted something or been derelict in my duty.

Comment: The first *slightly* suggests that John was queried about symptoms or otherwise offered an opportunity to report them.  The second *tends to imply* that it was totally up to John to report symptoms if he felt it appropriate.  But this is nothing you can count on.

Answer (score 3):

The basic difference surely lies in the two constructions

> John reported

and

> John did not report

In the first case, John performed an action: made a report telling someone that he has no symptoms.

In the second case, he has said nothing about any symptoms. He may even have said nothing at all about anything.

---

Edited after reading comment:

After reading Araucaria's comment, I've rethought my certainty, and now acknowledge that the two statements may be closer in meaning than I've said above. "John reported no symptoms" is indeed ambiguous, and therefore offers a fertile soil for litigation.

Comment: That doesn't seem a very likely story. In "she bore him no children" the sentence does not mean that the bore him something which was no children. Similarly in "he made no noise". I agree that the meanings you give are possible. But it cannot be possible that these are the "real meanings" and other readings are "not the real readings"

Comment: @Araucaria: Yes. I'm inclined to agree with you. I like your examples. But... Could you make the same argument for "John said he had no symptoms"? Doesn't this imply a definite statement from John? And if so, isn't "reported" another way of saying "said"? I'd like your thoughts.

Comment: @Araucaria ... +1... No my response won't do, will it? I sneaked in a "had". The original is not "John reported [that] he had no symptoms", which would be a definite statement. I think I'll have to give way. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: Hey don't let @Araucaria buffalo you! :) I had given you a +1 (much earlier) because I thought you were on the right path, and was basically providing a practical answer. (Aside: His example of "she bore him no children" seems more likely to be more of a special case; like who says stuff like that nowadays? *A: "Hey, how many kids do they have?", B: "His wife bore him no children.", A: "Huh?"* ) I think that your explanation is a solid way to start off an argumentation. It provides a clear launching pad, so to speak. imo.

Comment: Of course, there's stuff like: *A: "What did her uncle give her for her birthday?"*, where the response could be stuff like: "He didn't give her a gift", "He gave her nothing", "He gave absolutely nothing to her". And so, perhaps there's "When it was Tom's turn to report, he reported absolutely nothing", which is interesting, maybe. But "GIVE" is a special type of verb in some uses, maybe. But as to the verb "REPORT", hmm, . . . anyway. :)

Answer (score 2):

I think you're sort of on the right track. Here's how I see the two:

> John reported no symptoms.

This can mean a few different things and context (or emphasis if it's spoken) will probably tell you which is meant:

1. John reported [that there are] no symptoms.

   - John said that no symptoms exist.
   - I'd argue this is the more likely meaning.
2. John [did not] report [if there are] symptoms [or not].

   - We don't know if there are symptoms or not.
   - I'd say this is a secondary, less likely interpretation.

> John did not report any symptoms

With the other sentence, here are the options I see:

1. John did not report [that there are] any symptoms.

   - We don't know if symptoms have presented or not.
   - I'd say this is a *much* more likely interpretation.
2. John did not report [if there are] any symptoms.

   - We don't know if there are symptoms or not. The illness may not have any symptoms to look for.
   - I'd say this is less likely. I can't imagine an illness having no symptoms.

I have a difficult time making this version mean "John said no symptoms exist" but I can't completely exclude that interpretation. I think it's a bit ambiguous.

Now, as to whether John was asked if symptoms exist or not, I don't think either of these sentences imply that necessarily.

Let's pretend there's a form and part of that form is a section called "symptoms". I'd argue the first sentence would be more likely to imply that he filled in that section of the form with a phrase like "*no symptoms presented*". Whereas the second sentence is more likely to imply that that section of the form was left blank.